# Slower hops in traceroute

Tags: router, traceroute

What are the main reasons why some routers that appear in the traceroute output have a greater round trip time?

Comment: What protocol for traceroute?

Comment: In my experience the hops that have the greatest RTT when I do multiple traceroutes to the same host tend to be the same, no matter what protocol I use (icmp and tcp, mostly). What might be the reasons for that?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: add "no ip domain-lookup" on your router and check.. BR
Nitesh Arbale

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Many routers prioritize routing packets over answering ICMP requests, they often have rate limits and queueing in place to reduce load on the router.

As a result, latency on intermittent hops can be shown as higher than the latency to the end node.